# Spread operator stripping type definition in typescript

Tags: typescript

I ran into this strange phenomenon in typescript.  When using the spread operator, the type checking seems to be lost. I would expect this to throw an error:

```js
interface Input {
  thingOne: string;
  thingTwo: number;
  thingThree: string;
  thingFour: boolean;
  thingFive: Array<number>
}

interface Output {
  thingThree: string;
  thingFour: boolean;
  thingFive: Array<number>
}

const transformFunction = (input: Input): Output => {
  const result: Output = {
    ...input,
    thingFour: !input.thingFour
  }
  return result
}
```

#### [Typescript playground example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=21&ssc=2&pln=1&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIgA4FczIN4BQyyYAFqAOYDyIEAXMgM5hSUDcRJ5IFAKgO4B7BiCwBbAEbQOxMpV6koEekxbtOcngDFBWKAwmDBAGwhwQMrpS3AAbioCCUKHACeAHlGToAPgIBfAgJQSFhEFCocbFxCWW4+RWUGZlYeS00KHT0DI1NzdPibewYnFw8vKSg-QIIEQRBmEhcGmEEoMS0sEAQwYHrkAF5kAApQaIZ0aIBKBkiwaMGffE46htwlRixjMFmonEHl4mIAOlOxnAAaTjjrXX1kAEJzsGOMrKhOQOIlMD0QZA2WzAASAA)

I am typing `result` as `Output`, but spreading an object of type `Input` into it would clearly produce a result that is not of the type `Output`.  Why is typescript not catching this?

Comment: `Input` is assignable to `Output`, since types can have additional properties. You can simply return `input` instead of spreading it, and this will work too.

Comment: Would you mind elaborating?  For example, in [this TS playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIgA4FczIN4BQyyYAFqAOYDyIEAXMgM5hSUDcRJ5IFAKgO4B7BiCwBbAEbQOxMpV6koEekxbtOcngDFBWKAwmDBAGwhwQMrpS3AAbioCCUKHACeAHlGToAPgIBfAgJQSFhEFCocbFxCWW4+RWUGZlYeS00KHT0DI1NzdPibewYnFw8vKSg-QIIEQRBmZCVGLGMwBnRo5ABefA14hSUVAHJGYYAafutdfRIoLAhJuOs7FQBtACZxgGYAXQCguobcZtawAAYOzBwevuWeQaTkUYmp7RmGFgWlq21Vhk2O32-mQcEYyEiYGih3qjVObQ2DEhXV6sV+1FoDFGah4r3ufCEDC2bwSQyxYx+GSysy+ixJRXWWz2B1qsJOEBabW2SKiN1RJJoIxSlDx6IEwmQxPxjyFoqpHzm33p-2QgOZILBaGuYCAA)...

Comment: @Cerberus that does not justify why [Excess Property Check](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#excess-property-checks) does not trigger. OP has already explicitly mentioned the output type

Comment: why does `result3` work, but the others error?  Perhaps you can explain, or refer me to some docs, on how one type can be assignable to another?  Also, I can't just return `input`, as I am spreading it in, and then modifying a property (hence the whole reason for the transform function)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What we are expecting here is to trigger [Excess Property Check](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#excess-property-checks) feature of TypeScript. This feature tells us that TypeScript would warn us if there are extra properties in the object if we explicitly mention the object type. Unfortunately, it works only for object literals.

For example this:

```ts
const transformFunction = (input: Input): Output => {
  return {
    thingOne: "string;",
    thingTwo: 123,
    thingThree: "string;",
    thingFour: !input.thingFour,
    thingFive: [1, 23],
  };
};
```

Warns:

```ts
Type '{ thingOne: string; thingTwo: number; thingThree: string; thingFour: boolean; thingFive: number[]; }' is not assignable to type 'Output'.
  Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'thingOne' does not exist in type 'Output'.
```

It seems like spread operator case is not covered under exces property check. See here: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/41237

> This is the excess property check. According to @RyanCavanaugh it's more of a linter, not really part of the type system. But not every case is covered by this check, as you noticed.

They also mentioned looking into ongoing conversion on exact types here: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12936

Comment: This is one of those answers that is the answer, but is deeply unsatisfying lol.  I read those discussions.  So dumb.  Hopefully this will be addressed in typescript at some point in the near future.  Thanks for helping me understand what's going on.

Answer (score 1):

The function is type correct since type `Input` can be assigned to type `Output` without issues, even though it has extra properties. For literal objects only, there is an excess property check, because excess properties in a object literal are very likely to be mistakes. Consider this constant for example.

```
const o: {a: number} = {a: 1, b: 2}
```

As `o` now has type `{a: number}`, there is no typed way to access the `b` property, so TypeScript considers it an error.

Comment: Thanks for this...this helps solidify the kernel of the issue, which is that the spread operator is not included in excess property checks.  : (