# TypeScript is not capturing errors when adding wrong keys to objects

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux

I have `Person` type defined as below,

```
interface IPerson {
  name: string;
  age: number
}
```

Also, I'm creating a common type for all methods,

```
type IPersonMethod = (
  person: IPerson,
  newAge: number
) => IPerson;
```

My assumption is whenever I'm creating a new method with this type like below,

```
const updateAge: IPersonMethod = (person, newAge) => {
  return {
    ...person,
    age: newAge,
  }
}
```

It will only accept `person` of type `IPerson` and `age` of type `number` and will always return `IPerson` type object, so the above is working fine without any failures.

But if I add any wrong keys (let's say I typed `ag` instead of `age` by mistake), why is it not throwing any errors? (Below also works well which is not what I expected)

```
const updateAge: IPersonMethod = (person, newAge) => {
  return {
    ...person,
    ag: newAge,
  }
}
```

Comment: Read this- https://stackoverflow.com/a/66159772/11642727

Comment: Thanks shivam, so it's an open issue right?

Answer (score 1):

This happens because the `...person` has already the field `age` so you are actually returning a type `IPerson` with an extra wrong field `ag`. Typescript doesn't have support for restricting that extra property.

Comment: My biggest concern is, this is capturing the error, if I add a return to that method again, it's throwing errors properly, I mean this works well `const updateAge: IPersonMethod = (person, newAge): IPerson => {`

Comment: @MaranSowthri Then add IPerson after the function parens `(person, newAge): IPerson =>`. You will force ts to check the type of returning object.

Comment: correct, (that's what I did) but why should I do it twice is the question.